# How to get e.globalPoint in Titanium 3.1.0 GA

Tags: titanium

I am trying to get globalPoint in Titanium iPhone application when touchmove event occur, I use following code to get globalPoint

```
var x = parseInt(e.globalPoint.x, 10);
```

It work fine until I updated Titanium 3.0.2 GA to 3.1.0 GA, after updating I run the application I got following error

**'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'e.globalPoint.x')**

I am using this code for swiping window

```
var animateLeft = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
    left : 250,
    curve : Ti.UI.ANIMATION_CURVE_EASE_OUT,
    duration : 150
});

var animateRight = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
    left : 0,
    curve : Ti.UI.ANIMATION_CURVE_EASE_OUT,
    duration : 150
});

var touchStartX = 0;
var touchStarted = false;

$.innerwin.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
    touchStartX = parseInt(e.x, 10);
});

$.innerwin.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
    touchStarted = false;
    if ($.win.left >= 150) {
        $.win.animate(animateLeft);
        hasSlided = true;
    } else {
        $.win.animate(animateRight);
        hasSlided = false;
    }
});

$.innerwin.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    var x = parseInt(e.globalPoint.x, 10);
    var newLeft = x - touchStartX;
    if (touchStarted) {
        if (newLeft <= 250 && newLeft >= 0) {
            $.win.left = newLeft;
        }
    }
    if (newLeft > 30) {
        touchStarted = true;
    }
});

$.button.addEventListener('singletap', function(e) {
    $.toggleSlider();
});

var hasSlided = false;
exports.toggleSlider = function() {
    if (!hasSlided) {
        $.win.animate(animateLeft);
        hasSlided = true;
    } else {
        $.win.animate(animateRight);
        hasSlided = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This has been deprecated:](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-event-touchmove)

Instead you need to do this (in this very contrived example), and use the [convertPointToView](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-method-convertPointToView) method:

```
var baseview = Ti.UI.createView({width : Ti.UI.FILL, height : Ti.UI.FILL});
var view = Ti.UI.createView({ width : 20, height : 20 });
view.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    var globalPoint = convertPointToView({x : e.x, y : e.y}, baseview);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I used following widget

http://www.danielsefton.com/2013/05/slider-menu-widget-v2-for-titanium-alloy/